# How to disable saving default values from my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form with some time and date fields. For the date I use a `datepicker`. Currently I am able to save the default values for these fields and I am trying to disable that (unsuccessfully).

So my bootstrap form looks like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2 " class="dpckr" >
    <!-- <input class="form-control " id="date " name="date " placeholder="MM/DD/YYY " type="text "/> -->
      <input id="date" type="text " class="form-control datepicker" name="date" value="Click to select date">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="text ">Hour:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2 ">
      <select class="form-control " id="time">
        <option value="Time " class=" ">Time</option>
        <option value="10am " class=" ">10:00-10:30</option>
        <option value="1030am " class=" ">10:30-11:00</option>
        <option value="11am " class=" ">11:00-11:30</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am actually able to save the default `null` value for my date field and `Time` from my hour input. As far as I understand Bootstrap doesn't have validation and I am wondering how I can make this work with Javascript, so I can save only actual hours and dates.

Sorry if this question is too basic, I am a novice.

Comment: It looks like you want **required fields**, although I'm not familiar with that in Bootstrap

Comment: You need to look at scripting for that. Bootstrap is mostly for layouts and user interfacing.